# Can fiddler only capture https post method?

Tags: fiddler

Can fiddler only capture https post request/response?
Because I use windows Azure PS, I want to ignore HTTP GET method.
Can I do that with fiddler?

Comment: Using scripting you can. What have you tried?

Comment: BY using Azure powershell cmdlet, I want to only capture the post reqeust send by the powershell.